# How to execute .exe program in Python script?

Tags: python, subprocess, exe, os.system

I have a problem: I need to execute .exe in my python script. (This exe is compiled with VS, the DLL used is also in the current folder, I can run directly in cmd.) I searched that I can use `os. system ()` and `subprocess. call ()` online, but neither of them can work.Here are these error log：

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("BuildingTextureRDF.exe ./data/fujiaju_cycle.csv ./data/test.csv ./data/result_csv/114.374041130.449
92626.csv 0 3 4 5 1 2 -1 3.0 8 50.0 1000.0 1")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "F:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 267, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "F:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "F:\Users\hp\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
OSError:[WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

**My python info:**

`Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`

So I need change the python version?

If I use os.system():

```
os.system("BuildingTextureRDF.exe ./data/fujiaju_cycle.csv ./data/test.csv ./data/result_csv/114.374041130.44992626.
csv 0 3 4 5 1 2 -1 3.0 8 50.0 1000.0 1")
```

It pops up this interface:（The general meaning of the picture is:

```
This application cannot run on your computer
To find a version for your computer, consult the software publisher
```

.）

[image]

```
Deny access.
1
```

But,this exe run directly ok in cmd

```
PS H:\Flask> ./urban_texture/BuildingTextureRDF.exe ./urban_texture/data/fujiaju_cycle.csv ./urban_texture/data/test.csv
 ./urban_texture/data/result_csv/114.374041130.44992626.csv  0 3 4 5 1 2 -1 3.0 8 50.0 1000.0 1
Input Building File: ./urban_texture/data/fujiaju_cycle.csv
Input Lat Lon File: ./urban_texture/data/test.csv
Output Result File: ./urban_texture/data/result_csv/114.374041130.44992626.csv
FID COLUMN = 0
LATITUDE COLUMN = 3
LONGITUDE COLUMN = 4
PER FLOOR AREA COLUMN = 5
FLOORS COUNT COLUMN = 1
BUILDING HEIGHT COLUMN = 2
DEM HEIGHT COLUMN = -1
PER FLOOR HEIGHT = 3
* GEO-HASH SCALE = 8
* STEP RADIUS = 50
* MAXIMUM RADIUS = 1000
* IS NORMAILIZATION = 1
Load lat lon number: 1
2019-01-04 13:46:18 : GeoHash Scale = 8
2019-01-04 13:46:18 : Load file success. Total Number of Buildings = 279.
2019-01-04 13:46:18 : GeoHash Count = 222.
PROCESS FINISH.
```

Comment: What error does os.system give?

Comment: You may also want to try to set shell=True for subprocess.call

Comment: This application cannot run on your computer

To find a version for your computer, consult the software publisher.

Comment: Are you somehow magically running Python with different permissions from your normal user?

Comment: No, I just open commonly cmd and run python， neither  administrator and ordinary user can run ok.

Comment: I just tested,if I append shell=True, the same error as os.system( ) would happen.

Comment: What is the current directory for the python, and which directory is the exe in? Unless the exe is on the path, the two directories must be the same as you aren’t specifying the path to the exe.

Comment: @ Mad Physicist  I am sorry , I just found I cannot run it in cmd ,it run ok in Powershell using  command "./BuildingTextureRDF.exe ./data/fujiaju_cycle.csv ./data/test.csv ./data/result_csv/114.374041130.44992626.csv 0 3 4 5 1 2 -1 3.0 8 50.0 1000.0 1"

Comment: @ barny  I opened python in the same directory as ,exe

Comment: Is your OS 32bit?

Comment: No，my system is 64bit